# Get last order ID from a purchased product ID in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

How to get order id of a specific product if the customer has bought the product? I tried the below code but did not work. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<?php
 $order = new wc_get_order( $order_id );
 $order->get_id();
 echo $order->get_order_number();
?>
```

Tried this code also but didn't worked.

```
$product_ids = array(37,53);
$order_ids = get_order_ids_from_bought_items( $product_ids );
```

Comment: Whats the input you have ( user id / order id / product id )? which one?

Comment: @mujeebu i have product id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_order_ids_from_bought_items() {

    $prod_arr = array('37', '53');
    $purchased = false;

    $customer_orders = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
            ));
    foreach ($customer_orders as $order_post) {


        $order = wc_get_order($order_post->ID);

        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {

            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

            if (in_array($product_id, $prod_arr))
                $purchased = true;
        }
    }

    return $purchased; // $order_post->ID  for Order ID
}
```

Comment: I want order id if customer has bought the product. Will the above code help to get id?

Comment: @PullataPraveen Updated answer

Comment: where shall I add the above code? I want to display the order id in custom template.

Comment: If you're looking for an automatic notification type of system when a specific product is placed, I'd set-up a webhook in WooCommerce. Set the delivery URL to your script that searches for the product in the response and does whatever you'd like. Otherwise if you just want a page or what-have-you that gives you this information when you access it, the above answer looks fitting.

Comment: @PullataPraveen You can use it in functions.php file with minor modification like paasing the product array from where you are calling and remove from function - also wrap the function inside if function_exists(

Comment: Put it in your functions.php file it will be available across all pages/templates/etc

Answer (score 2):

The following function uses a very lightweight SQL query that will return the last order Id from a defined product Id for a given customer:

```
function get_last_order_id_from_product( $product_id, $user_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;

    return $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON p.ID = woi.order_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
        AND woim.meta_key IN ( '_product_id', '_variation_id' )
        AND woim.meta_value = $product_id
        ORDER BY p.ID DESC  LIMIT 1
    " );
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If the customer has not purchased the product yet the function will return **`false`**.

**USAGE Examples:**

Here below you will set the Product Id **`37`** and optionally the user Id ***`153`***(if you don't use the code for front end where the function can get the current user Id)*/

```
$order_id = get_last_order_id_from_product( 37, 153 );
```

Or for the current user:

```
$order_id = get_last_order_id_from_product( 37 );
```